# Japanese font is very low quality for no apparent reason

Tags: symbols, font-encodings

Recently, I was experimenting with LaTeX in terms of glyph encoding. Of course, the best way to do that is to compile multiple documents with different language settings. All was fine until I came to the Japanese language. Here is a MWE to illustrate my point:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}未練なく散も桜はさくら哉\end{CJK} \\
without regret \\
they fall and scatter\ldots \\
cherry blossoms

\end{document}
```

Of course the document compiles just fine, but there's a problem. **The Japanese glyphs are low quality.** It is similar to `OT1` on unsupported `babel` packages:

[image]

It is kind of hard to see, but I assure you that the Japanese text is of worse quality than the Latin letters. I tried loading `[OT1]{fontenc}`, `[T1]{fontenc}`, `[japanese]{babel}` and `[UTF8]{inputenc}` but the result of the compilation remained the same.

I'd like to know how to remove this aesthetic imperfection. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** The requested `.log` file is too long (SE accepts up to 30000 characters only), so I saved it to Google Drive. You can get it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-euccGmliZiZXFtYkQ0UWNhSmM).

Comment: If you zoom a lot on the Latin text, is it a vector image or can you see pixels (like you see with the Japanese text, but already without zooming)?

Comment: It is okay for me in texlive 2017, type1-fonts are used. In miktex it doesn't compile for me as the fonts are missing. Show your log-file.

Comment: @Karlo I can see pixels in Japanese texts, but the Latin text is a vector image.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The log file was over 30000 characters, so SE didn't want to accept it. I added it to Google Drive in `.txt` format and shared the link in my edit. I hope this is satisfactory.

Comment: miktex. Well cjk-fonts in miktex are a constant (and old see e.g. https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2095/) problem. The fonts are either missing or incomplete. One quite often has to install the fonts manually (when needed I copy them from texlive ...).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Should I switch from MikTeX to TeXLive? I'm doing a complete renewal of my repositories soon, so be sure to let me know. I've had random access errors and other nasty stuff in MiKTeX configuration (not my fault, rather the bugs are to blame) so I'm pretty sick of it. A new, complete system that works as intended would be a fresh breath of air for me. Will TeXStudio work with TeXLive though?

Comment: I have both. Some things are better in texlive (cjk-fonts), other exist only in miktex (e.g. acrotex).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried having both, but their configuration just messed everything up and confused the living hell out of my LaTeX compiler. I was struck with a pile of errors every day and got frustrated quickly, so I chose (at the time) the simpler one.

Comment: Using a standard class such as `article` will reduce the log for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: Off-topic: never end lines like that in regular text!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard Japanese font in CJK package (min) is terrible, but you can use "ipxm" instead if you have [ipaex-type1](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ipaex-type1). It is based on [IPAex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ipaex) (ttf format), which is widely used as default Japanese font on TeX Live environment (pLaTeX + dvipdfmx, upLaTeX + dvipdfmx, LuaLaTeX (with luatexja package), etc.). The quality is high enough for practical use, from native Japanese point of view.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{ipxm}未練なく散も桜はさくら哉\end{CJK} \\
without regret \\
they fall and scatter\ldots \\
cherry blossoms

\end{document}
```

[image]