# Tips for printing LaTeX documents

Tags: printing

When printing my papers, I noticed something odd: while the letters of documents exported from Word were clean around the edges, PDF compiled by LaTeX usually had some kind of grainy imperfections in letter cursive. This perplexes me, as there shouldn't be any difference between the two documents — they are both PDF. Are there any options that can be added to the source code to fix this problem or at least enhance the quality of the prints? Thank you for your answers in advance.

EDIT

Due to request, here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[slovene,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

Slovenian: Zakaj so moje črke zmazane? \\

English (translation): Why are my letters blurry?

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I use `T1`, so `OT1` encoding can't be an issue. I don't know if `slovene` babel font is scalable though.

EDIT 2

Here you go, (perhaps) the log file.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.10.25)  16 FEB 2018 22:07
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./tikzducks-doc.tex
(./tikzducks-doc.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.14> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15

(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00AD (decimal 173)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
   defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
   defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
   defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
   defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
   defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
   defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
   defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
   defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
   defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
   defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
   defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
   defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
   defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
   defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
   defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
   defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
   defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
   defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
   defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
   defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
   defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
   defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
   defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
   defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
   defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
   defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
   defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
   defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
   defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
   defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
   defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
   defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
   defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
   defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
   defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
   defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
   defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
   defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
   defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
   defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
   defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
   defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
   defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
   defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
   defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
   defining Unicode char U+0100 (decimal 256)
   defining Unicode char U+0101 (decimal 257)
   defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)
   defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)
   defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)
   defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)
   defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)
   defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)
   defining Unicode char U+0108 (decimal 264)
   defining Unicode char U+0109 (decimal 265)
   defining Unicode char U+010A (decimal 266)
   defining Unicode char U+010B (decimal 267)
   defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)
   defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)
   defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)
   defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)
   defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)
   defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)
   defining Unicode char U+0112 (decimal 274)
   defining Unicode char U+0113 (decimal 275)
   defining Unicode char U+0114 (decimal 276)
   defining Unicode char U+0115 (decimal 277)
   defining Unicode char U+0116 (decimal 278)
   defining Unicode char U+0117 (decimal 279)
   defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)
   defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)
   defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)
   defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)
   defining Unicode char U+011C (decimal 284)
   defining Unicode char U+011D (decimal 285)
   defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)
   defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)
   defining Unicode char U+0120 (decimal 288)
   defining Unicode char U+0121 (decimal 289)
   defining Unicode char U+0122 (decimal 290)
   defining Unicode char U+0123 (decimal 291)
   defining Unicode char U+0124 (decimal 292)
   defining Unicode char U+0125 (decimal 293)
   defining Unicode char U+0128 (decimal 296)
   defining Unicode char U+0129 (decimal 297)
   defining Unicode char U+012A (decimal 298)
   defining Unicode char U+012B (decimal 299)
   defining Unicode char U+012C (decimal 300)
   defining Unicode char U+012D (decimal 301)
   defining Unicode char U+012E (decimal 302)
   defining Unicode char U+012F (decimal 303)
   defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)
   defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)
   defining Unicode char U+0134 (decimal 308)
   defining Unicode char U+0135 (decimal 309)
   defining Unicode char U+0136 (decimal 310)
   defining Unicode char U+0137 (decimal 311)
   defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)
   defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)
   defining Unicode char U+013B (decimal 315)
   defining Unicode char U+013C (decimal 316)
   defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)
   defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)
   defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)
   defining Unicode char U+0145 (decimal 325)
   defining Unicode char U+0146 (decimal 326)
   defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)
   defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)
   defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)
   defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)
   defining Unicode char U+014C (decimal 332)
   defining Unicode char U+014D (decimal 333)
   defining Unicode char U+014E (decimal 334)
   defining Unicode char U+014F (decimal 335)
   defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)
   defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)
   defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)
   defining Unicode char U+0156 (decimal 342)
   defining Unicode char U+0157 (decimal 343)
   defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)
   defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)
   defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)
   defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)
   defining Unicode char U+015C (decimal 348)
   defining Unicode char U+015D (decimal 349)
   defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)
   defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)
   defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
   defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
   defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)
   defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)
   defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)
   defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)
   defining Unicode char U+0168 (decimal 360)
   defining Unicode char U+0169 (decimal 361)
   defining Unicode char U+016A (decimal 362)
   defining Unicode char U+016B (decimal 363)
   defining Unicode char U+016C (decimal 364)
   defining Unicode char U+016D (decimal 365)
   defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)
   defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)
   defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)
   defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)
   defining Unicode char U+0172 (decimal 370)
   defining Unicode char U+0173 (decimal 371)
   defining Unicode char U+0174 (decimal 372)
   defining Unicode char U+0175 (decimal 373)
   defining Unicode char U+0176 (decimal 374)
   defining Unicode char U+0177 (decimal 375)
   defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
   defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)
   defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)
   defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)
   defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)
   defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
   defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
   defining Unicode char U+01CD (decimal 461)
   defining Unicode char U+01CE (decimal 462)
   defining Unicode char U+01CF (decimal 463)
   defining Unicode char U+01D0 (decimal 464)
   defining Unicode char U+01D1 (decimal 465)
   defining Unicode char U+01D2 (decimal 466)
   defining Unicode char U+01D3 (decimal 467)
   defining Unicode char U+01D4 (decimal 468)
   defining Unicode char U+01E2 (decimal 482)
   defining Unicode char U+01E3 (decimal 483)
   defining Unicode char U+01E6 (decimal 486)
   defining Unicode char U+01E7 (decimal 487)
   defining Unicode char U+01E8 (decimal 488)
   defining Unicode char U+01E9 (decimal 489)
   defining Unicode char U+01EA (decimal 490)
   defining Unicode char U+01EB (decimal 491)
   defining Unicode char U+01F0 (decimal 496)
   defining Unicode char U+01F4 (decimal 500)
   defining Unicode char U+01F5 (decimal 501)
   defining Unicode char U+0218 (decimal 536)
   defining Unicode char U+0219 (decimal 537)
   defining Unicode char U+021A (decimal 538)
   defining Unicode char U+021B (decimal 539)
   defining Unicode char U+0232 (decimal 562)
   defining Unicode char U+0233 (decimal 563)
   defining Unicode char U+1E02 (decimal 7682)
   defining Unicode char U+1E03 (decimal 7683)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2010 (decimal 8208)
   defining Unicode char U+2011 (decimal 8209)
   defining Unicode char U+2012 (decimal 8210)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2015 (decimal 8213)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
   defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
   defining Unicode char U+1E20 (decimal 7712)
   defining Unicode char U+1E21 (decimal 7713)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00AD (decimal 173)
   defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+0174 (decimal 372)
   defining Unicode char U+0175 (decimal 373)
   defining Unicode char U+0176 (decimal 374)
   defining Unicode char U+0177 (decimal 375)
   defining Unicode char U+0218 (decimal 536)
   defining Unicode char U+0219 (decimal 537)
   defining Unicode char U+021A (decimal 538)
   defining Unicode char U+021B (decimal 539)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2017/10/04 3.14 The Babel package

(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2017/10/04 3.14 Babel switching mechanism
)
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-slovenian/slovene.ldf
Language: slovene 2005/03/31 v1.2m Slovene support from the babel system

(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2017/10/04 3.14 Babel common definitions

(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2017/10/04 3.14 Babel switching mechanism
)
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 79.
)
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
))
(./tikzducks-doc.aux)
\openout1 = `tikzducks-doc.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 9--10

 []

[1

{c:/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./tikzducks-doc.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1250 strings out of 492990
 13434 string characters out of 6136333
 73608 words of memory out of 5000000
 4853 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4403 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,4n,23p,181b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-
super-t1.enc}<c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.p
fb>
Output written on tikzducks-doc.pdf (1 page, 16447 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: People will be able to help you better if you include a sample document that illustrates the issue (and perhaps even a PDF). The most likely cause is that the PDF is using a bitmap font at a resolution lower than (not translating well to) that of the printer. But without an example, it's just guesswork.

Comment: A couple of your previous questions ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388074/japanese-font-is-very-low-quality-for-no-apparent-reason), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392913/font-is-lower-quality-with-t1-than-ot1-on-texlive)) indicate you have some sub-optimal fonts setup in your TeX installation; what you observe here may be related to that.

Comment: you are most likely using bitmap fonts. Almost all fonts usable from TeX are available in scalable format these days so there might be something wrong with your setup or you might be using a font that is only available as metafont generated bitmaps. impossible to say given no information in the question.

Comment: Will add edit with MWE to help determine the cause in a minute.

Comment: Check the end of the log-file. If fonts with the extension `.pk` are reported you should install the cm-super package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, I found 0 fonts reported with `.pk` (I opened `log.txt` and used Ctrl+F to make sure).

Comment: The log is not "log.txt" but a file with the ending log. Better show the log-file so that we can that you have the correct one and look for the fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've posted my supposed log file. I hope that helps.

Comment: Looks ok, the file uses only pfb (type1-fonts), it shouldn't be blurry. Where do you see the problem? On screen? Can you zoom in and make a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: No, the pdf is absolutely fine, vector scaling and all that. The problem is that when I PRINT the compiled pdf, the quality of the text is significantly worse compared to a pdf exported from Word. My problem is of "physical" nature.

Comment: Is this specific document something that causes the issue when printed? Can you include the pdf and/or a picture of the printed page?

Comment: Right now, I have only my mobile device at hand. So it can't be helped.

Comment: Yeah that's fine, the question can wait till you're back at a computer. :-) Another reason for asking is that the question mentions “imperfections in letter cursive”, but the example doesn't include any cursive letters (as I understand it). So it may not be an example of a document that causes a problem when printed.

Comment: What is this cursive font? If this font has been designed by Metafont, it could explain why it looks somewhat okay within the PDF viewer and grainy with the printer, since it's bitmap and must be adapted to the printer's resolution to look all right.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR "Cursives" as in edges of the letters. To my understanding, 'cursive font' (like italics bold or something) isn't equal to 'letter cursives' — this is every point on the letter's edge where the letter "loops". For example, gothic manuscript has very few cursives. I'll post the comparison in a follow-up question.